# Customising Google script Authorization request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a few custom scripts on a google sheet workbook that I share with some co-workers.

One of the scripts asks for way to much permission when we try to run it.

- Read, send, delete, and manage email.
- View and manage files.
- etc.

Basically SUDO privilege.

[Picture of permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxyOP.png)

How can I modify and choose the minimum requirements the script needs?

The script is as follows:

```
    function addLine() {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.insertRows(2);

    if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();

    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm:ss");
    if(row != 1) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R' + row.toString()).setValue( 
       time );
    }
  };
}`
```

Thanks,

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can not customize it. GAS automatically lists the scopes based on your code :)

Answer (score 0):

GAS won't ask for permission to `Read, send, delete, and manage email.` unless you have the `MailApp` or `GmailApp` used somewhere in your code? So I assume this is not your full code.

Also, these permissions only apply to the account that authorises them. What I mean is, if you grant permission to this script only your account can run the scripts as you. If your co-workers try to run the script they will be asked to authorise to it and then the script will be called using their account.

Your co-workers can't use this to access your emails or send emails as you etc.